# Let a,b,c,d $\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $d|a$ and $d|bc$, then $d|c$.

Tags: number-theory

Problem: Let $a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $d|a$ and $d|bc$, then $d|c$.

I know that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there exits $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ st $as+bt=1$
And since $d|a$ and $d|bc$ then there exists $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ st $dm=a$ and $dn=bc$. But now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $as+bt =1$, and therefore $asc+bct=c$.  Now from $d\mid a$ and $d\mid bc$  we conclude that $d\mid c$.

For in your notation $a=md$ and $bc=nd$ so $c=d(msc+nt)$.

Comment: I kept trying to prove that in the end d|bc and not d|c! A lot easier when you look at the problem correctly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.